# How do I get the first previous non-zero cell in column using an Excel Formula?

Tags: excel-formula

**Consider the following spreadsheet snippet:**

[image]

I'm trying to write the following forumla:

```
For a give row, for the same Sales#:
   If Type=1 OR Type=2, go the first non-zero previous cell in the column
   and copy the lineprice
```

I know how to examine the type field:

```
=IF((OR(VALUE(BA7)=1,VALUE(BA7)=2)), ?????, "")
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve the lineprice.
I would like to do this via a formula if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting the formula?  Are you going to put them in the green cells?  If so, where do the `0` and the first `10.9` come from?  Just making sure you are not creating a circular formula situation.

Comment: Scot Craner: Yes, I should have been explicit. Formulae to go into green cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(C7={1,2}),INDEX($B$1:$B6,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($B$2:$B6)/(($A$2:$A$6=A7)*($B$2:$B6<>0)),1)),0)
```

[image]